# aws cognito login usuario flutter

Tags: flutter, login, aws, excepciones, cognito

estoy utilizando amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2: ^3.5.0 para integrar AWS Cognito en mi aplicación móvil.

Para iniciar sesión exitosamente, mis usuarios deben ingresar su nombre de usuario (no ingresan password) y luego responder un desafío que llega a su correo electrónico e ingresar los 6 dígitos en mi aplicación.

para esto estoy usando

```
await Auth.initiateAuth(authDetails);
```

este método devuelve una excepción que dice CUSTOM_CHALLENGE (que es válida y esperada dado mi flujo personalizado).

luego con

```
Auth.sendCustomChallengeAnswer(código de verificación);
```

Envío los 6 dígitos ingresados ​​por el usuario, pero aquí empiezan los problemas, porque según sendCustomChallengeAnswer me falta el parámetro Session, que en teoría debería llenarse con la respuesta initiateAuth, pero este método no responde a un objeto de sesión. , de lo contrario responde a una cadena de su excepción llamada CUSTOM_CHALLANGE

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo solucionar esto?

paquete de enlaces que estoy usando: https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2

Necesito saber si es una mala interpretación o un error de paquete